# Converting a Winform application to a service (Best way)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf, service

I have (or the company) a simple watchdog application that monitors memory, diskspace and some connections and other stuff realated to a realtime database server. We are using this application to detect errors and notify system administrators by email about faults. We also send a daily report on som KPI and other stuff.

The problem is that there need to be someone logged inn to the server at all time with this solution (it was created simple just for monitoring some problems we had but has become a application we like to futher develop) and we like to convert it to a service to avoid that someone needs to be logged on at all time.

The application is written in C# framework 3.5. I know there is WCF and other stuff now. I looked in VS (version 2012) and i see that the even removed the Service project that used to be there, and there is now only WCF.

I dont have to much experice in that field (.NET technology) since i've only done legacy C++ programming the last 5 years at work.

Does anyone have som recommandation for doing this the best way ?

Comment: As suggested by Reed , i am adding a bit more, after wraaping your logic to dll , either in C++ or C#, from Services.msc, add it to list and set it to atomatic mode. so you need not to require any sort of interaction evertime\

Comment: Sounds like you need a windows service more than a WCF service. WCF services are 'called' by a client process. Also, monitoring local disk from a web service can be dicey, if even possible. A windows service can run/go to sleep/wake up, do cool stuff, go back to sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move all of your logic into a class library, you can just create a new Service Project, and use that library within the service that's generated.

MSDN has a [walkthrough on creating services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx) that walks through the process, step by step.

Comment: I discussed this with my collegues. We decided to go for this solution.